# "An unknown error has occurred" is output when installing RHEL 8.3 on fresh system

Tags: rhel, system-installation, bugs, installer-anaconda

I have a laptop that I am installing RHEL 8.3 for Developer.

I get an error: `An unknown error has occurred`.

Reference is made to anaconda and I find some aspect on RHEL portal. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5116361

However, this does not help me as, I am following the standard install procedure. I cannot see how to circumvent. I am going to a basic install.

Any ideas.

Comment: Report it, it is a bug.

Comment: OK, what is a work-around though? I need to move away from CENTOS. @GAD3R

Comment: @GAD3R  8.2 a goer?

Comment: Maybe! try it out.

Comment: @GAD3R  well somewhat disappointing to waste time

Comment: This bug in the latest rhel release, older releases seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed RHEL 8.2, no such issue.

As GAD3R stated it appears to be a bug.

[Bug 1921159 Submitted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1921159)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and they are resolving it.As a workaround you can uncheck the " Connect to red hat insights" and start installation.It works. [image]. The bug is https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1931069